# How do we statically initialize test data before calling a test method?

Tags: f#, .net-core, xunit

We have the following test set up.

**Permutations.Tests.fsproj**

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="Permute1Tests.fs" />
  <Compile Include="Permute2Tests.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Permute1Tests.fs**

```
module Permute1Tests

open Xunit
open Permutations.Permute1

[<Theory>]
[<MemberData("permuteTestValues")>]
let ``permute`` (x, expected) =
    let actual = permute x
    Assert.Equal<List<int>>(expected, actual);

let permuteTestValues : obj array seq =
    seq {
        yield [| [0;1]; [[0;1]; [1;0]] |]
    }
```

**Permute2Tests.fs**

```
module Permute2Tests

open Xunit
open Permutations.Permute2

[<Theory>]
[<MemberData("removeFirstTestData")>]
let ``removeFirst`` (item, list, expected: List<int>) =
    let actual = removeFirst list item
    Assert.Equal<List<int>>(expected, actual)

let removeFirstTestData : obj array seq =
    seq {
        yield [| 0; [1;2;3;4]; [1;2;3;4] |]
    }
```

When we run `dotnet test`, this is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Test data returned null for Permute2Tests.removeFirst. Make sure it is statically initialized before this test method is called.

Oddly enough, `Permute1Tests.fs` runs without error. Its test passes. And, if we swap the `Permute1Test.fs` position in the `ItemGroup` with the `Permute2Test.fs`, then the latter now works and the former has the error.

How do we statically initialize test data before calling a test method? It seems that `ItemGroup` order matters in our current approach, and that makes our current approach fail.

The full version of the above code [is here](https://github.com/shaunluttin/algorithms/tree/master/articles/functional-programs-for-generating-permutations/FSharp/Permutations.Tests).

## Edit: ILSpy Output

**Permute1Tests.fs.cs**

```
// <StartupCode$Permutations-Tests>.$Permute1Tests
using <StartupCode$Permutations-Tests>;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

internal static class $Permute1Tests
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    internal static readonly IEnumerable<object[]> permuteTestValues@12;

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal static int init@;

    static $Permute1Tests()
    {
        IEnumerable<object[]> permuteTestValues = 
            $Permute1Tests.permuteTestValues@12 = 
                (IEnumerable<object[]>)new Permute1Tests.permuteTestValues@14(0, null);
    }
}
```

**Permute2Tests.fs.cs**

```
// <StartupCode$Permutations-Tests>.$Permute2Tests
using <StartupCode$Permutations-Tests>;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

internal static class $Permute2Tests
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    internal static IEnumerable<object[]> removeFirstTestData@15;

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal static int init@;

    public static void main@()
    {
        IEnumerable<object[]> removeFirstTestData = 
            $Permute2Tests.removeFirstTestData@15 = 
                (IEnumerable<object[]>)new Permute2Tests.removeFirstTestData@17(0, null);
    }
}
```

**Permutations.Test.fsproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Permute1Tests.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Permute2Tests.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Permutations\Permutations.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you look at the compiled code with ILSpy and see if the two modules are different in some way? If that doesn't lead you to discover the problem, please post result of ILSpy decompilation to C#.

Comment: I can confirm that the two modules are not different. The most unusual thing, is that if we swap the order of the two files in the *.fsproj ItemGroup list, then the error happens in the opposite file. That's evidence that the only difference between the modules is the order in which they appear in the ItemGroup list. @FyodorSoikin

Comment: Can you please post the result of ILSpy decompilation?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've added the ILSpy output and it did indeed give some insight.

Comment: Almost got it! Can you also post the _full_ contents of your `fsproj` file?

Comment: The answer presented itself to me: add a `Program.fs` file with `module Program = let [<EntryPoint>] main _ = 0` in it. It isn't entirely clear why. Though we have some ideas, we would welcome an answer that explains what's going on here.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin We added the full `fsproj` settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why

This has to do with the fact that your assembly is an "executable" (i.e. a program with an entry point) rather than a "library".

F# compiles executables slightly differently than libraries: in the module where the entry point is located, all static data is initialized inside the `main` function, before executing everything else; in all other modules, static data is initialized in static constructors. I am not sure what was the reasoning behind this decision, but this is how the F# compiler behaves.

Next, how does the F# compiler determine which module contains the entry point? Very simple: whichever module is the last one, that's where the entry point is. To think of it, this is the only sensible choice: since F# has compilation order, only the very last file can have access to definitions in all other files; therefore, that's where the entry point must be.

So, in your example, whichever module was last in the list, ended up with a `main` function, in which the static initialization code was located. And since the unit test runner doesn't run the entry point before executing tests, the static data in that module remained uninitialized.

### Solution 1: add an artificial module to contain the entry point

As you have already discovered yourself, one solution is to add an artificial module that contains nothing but the entry point. That way, the test module won't be the last one anymore, won't contain the entry point, and therefore its data will be initialized in the static constructor.

The artificial module doesn't even have to have an `[<EntryPoint>] main` function, it could just be this:

```
module Dummy
let _x = 0  // `do ()` would be even shorter, but that will create a warning
```

The compiler will add an entry point anyway.

### Solution 2: compile to `netstandard2.0`

If you switch your target from `netcoreapp2.0` to `netstandard2.0`, your assembly will be considered a "library" rather than an "executable", and the compiler won't add an entry point, and won't put static initialization in it.